# Inserting into a linked list alphabetically in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Can anyone provide a brief example of how to use the strcmp() function for inserting a new node into a linked list alphabetically based on the first item in a pointer struct. Not really looking for a answer but more just a explanation with a ambiguous example could not really find a straight answer out there so I hoped someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some of your previous work! what does your list look like? how do you traverse it? ...

Comment: strcmp tells you if the thing you're comparing comes before or after something different.. so you know if you've gone too far in your list.  Likely you just go until it says you've gone too far, then put it right before that one.

Comment: I have a very strong urge tore-tag this question with homework. Looks like a homework question

Comment: @darnir I've been told the homework tag isn't used any more. But I agree, this does look like homework. For what it's worth, I'd go with xaxxon's method.

Comment: Have a look at this questions answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15960040/1025391 (use strcmp to compare the node values)

Comment: It is definitely homework (yes, I want the homework tag back, too) Let him explain the pointer to function and the pointer to pointer to his teacher. Or: to his future employer.

Comment: I wish these questions would be closed before people ignore things about not doing people's homework for them for some easy internet points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go (this one uses a pointer to function)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
    char *value;
    struct llist *next;
};

int compare (struct llist *one , struct llist *two)
{
return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}

void add(struct llist **pp, char *value, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r)) {

    struct llist *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->value = value;

    for ( ; *pp != NULL; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
        if (cmp(*pp, new) > 0 ) break;
        }

    new->next = *pp;
    *pp = new;
}

void display(struct llist *ptr) {

    for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct llist *root = NULL;

    add(&root, "item1", compare);
    add(&root, "item2", compare);
    add(&root, "item4", compare);
    add(&root, "item3", compare);

    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what part of not doing people's homework do you not really get?  Also, he SAID he wasn't looking for an answer.

Comment: `but more just a explanation with a ambiguous example ` Looks more like an **un** ambiguous example to me. BTW: see my comment under the OQ. If he can explain it to the teacher he learned a lot. If he can't, he's doomed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your linked list node looks something like the following:

```
typedef struct node {
    char* str;
    struct node* next;
} NODE;
```

If you are inserting a new node into a linked list sorted by alphabetically, there are four cases to consider:

1. The list is empty and the node to be inserted is therefore the first / only node
2. The node to be inserted is alphabetically before the first node in the list
3. The node is to be inserted into the middle
4. The node is to be inserted at the end of the list.

Assuming, however, that:

1. An empty list is properly set to `NULL`, and
2. The node to be inserted has its `next` properly set to `NULL`

you can handle insertions by combining the first two cases and the last two cases, so that you have only one logical choice: you are inserting the new node either as the first node, or as some other node in the list.

Here is a straightforward algorithm that tackles these two cases.

```
algorithm insert

receives: list, pointer to linked list
    toInsert, pointer to new node for insertion

returns: pointer to updated list with new node inserted. 

1. if (list is null OR toInsert->value is less than list->value)  
    1.1 set toInsert->next to list
    1.2 set list to toInsert
2. else
    2.1 set pPre to list
    2.2 set pWalk to list->next
    2.3 loop while (pWalk is not null AND toInsert->value is greater than pPre->value)
        2.3.1 set pPre to pWalk;
        2.3.2 set pWalk to pWalk->next;
    2.4 set pPre->next to toInsert;    
    2.5 set toInsert->next to pWalk;
3. return
```

To implement this, you will have to use `strcmp()` in both the `if` and the `while` conditions.

Bear in mind that `strcmp()` compares strings by ASCII order, not "alphabetically". `'B'` comes after `'A'` but before `'a'` as far as `strcmp()` is concerned. If you need a strict alphabetic sort that is case-insensitive, you'll have to write your own version of `strcmp()` that ignores case, and use a function pointer in your `insert()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the linked list is already alphabetically sorted, then you have to iterate to the first node that should be after the new node and insert the new node before it. You need to remember the node before the current node in the iteration, because the last node's `next` pointer should now be pointing the new node. You might have to handle some cases uniquely, like if the list has size zero or if you insert at the borders.

Beware of the difference between alphabetical sorting and sorting by ascii. It's different. (alphabetical: 11 > 9, ascii: 11 < 9)